# How do I install the open-cv library for use in Pycharm IDE on a Ubuntu 16.04 system using pip?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

`main.py` : has line `import cv2`, but on running

`python main.py` and error is thrown.

**EDIT:**

`pip install opencv-python` installs cv2 package.

Comment: which python is pycharm using? is it the same python into which you install cv2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the package? Try running

```
pip install opencv-python
```

in the command line prompt, the proceed with `import cv2` in a python console.

Comment: I have tried that, this is what I get for doing that : 

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for cv2

Comment: Ah yes, apparently the the package is called `opencv-python` on pip. Edited answer to reflect--does this work?

Comment: Yes it did. `opencv-python` did the job.

Answer (score -1):

Follow These Steps in this Tutorial:-

https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/